# Compilation fails with gmail connector in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

```
gmail:Client gmail = check new ({auth: {token: gmailToken}});
gmail:Message sendMessage = check gmail->sendMessage(messageRequest);
```

With the above code, I get the following compilation error.

```
ERROR [main.bal:(30:46,30:57)] undefined method 'sendMessage' in object 'ballerinax/googleapis.gmail:4.0.0:Client'
error: compilation contains errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ballerinax/googleapis.gmail`  version `4.0.0` doesn't have `sendMessage API`.

Check https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/googleapis.gmail/latest.

I think you can use https://central.ballerina.io/ballerinax/googleapis.gmail/latest#Client-post-users-string-userId-messages-send to send a message as follows.

```
Message message = check gmailClient->/users/<userID>/messages/send.post(messageRequest);
```